# Getting external variables inside Angular.js factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am giving my first steps with Angular.js and I am facing a little problem which I don't know how to deal with Angular. I know many jQuery ways for solving it, but I am sure that it may exists an Angular way:

Firstly, I have an select element set with `currentPlant` as `ng-model`

```
  <select class="form-control" name="planta" ng-model='currentPlant' ng-options='plant.name for plant in plants' >
  </select>
```

I print the current name as page title, I see this element updating when I change the selected value, so I am sure that **`currentPlant` is being correctly updated**.

```
<h1>{{ currentPlant ? currentPlant.name : 'Seleccione una planta'}}</h1>
```

Now I have the following button:

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='loadTowers()'>
  Cargar torres
</button>
```

When the button is pressed, the `loadTowers` function is executed, and is now when the problems start. I have set the `loadTowers` function in the controller that way:

```
$scope.loadTowers = plants.towers;
```

`plant` is a angular service which has implemented the `towers` function inside. I need to get the value of `currentPlant` inside this function. Take a look:

```
.factory('plants', ['$http',function($http){
  var o = {
    plants: [],

    towers : []
  };


  o.towers =  function(){
     var id = ¿?; // I NEED SET THIS VARIABLE WITH THE currentPlant.id VALUE 
     $http.get('/api/v1/plants/'+id+'/towers')
     .success(function(data){
         angular.copy(data, o.towers);
      })
     }
    return o;
   }]);
```

I could set an `data-plant` attribute in the option element, and get the selected through jQuery, but I am trying avoid this kind of solutions. How do you deal with this?

**NOTE:** Take account that I simply want get the `option` selected when I press the button and make different `get` requests to the API`in function of that through the service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the value in the ngclick:

```
     <button ng-click='loadTowers(currentPlant)'>
```

Then add it in the factory args:

```
    o.towers =  function(currentPlant){

    }
```